# TypeError: generator() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I use the keyboard shortcut, the error does not show, but if I use the mouse event, the program throws an error:

```
TypeError: generator () takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I would like both events to work. In my opinion, this applies to the `window.bind` and `button_003.bind ("<ButtonRelease-1>", Generating_code.generator)`

Here's code:

```
class Generator:
    def generator(self,event):

        if entry_01.get() == ("") or entry_szt1.get() == (""):

            tkMessageBox.showerror("Błąd", "Uzupełnij Numer reklamacji !")

        else:

            button_003 = Button(pageq,
                                text="Generuj kod",
                                font="none 20",
                                state=DISABLED
                                )
            button_003.place(x=1112, y=95)

            teraz = datetime.datetime.now()
            time = (teraz.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

            output = (time)
            output.split('.')
            dzien, miesiac, rok = output.split(".")
            rokk = rok
            mies = miesiac
            dzie = dzien
            my_list = list(rokk)
            one, two, three, four = my_list
            konc_roku = three + four
            k_roku = int(konc_roku)
            m = int(mies)
            tydzien = datetime.date(k_roku, m, 01).isocalendar()[1]
            data_biezaca = str(tydzien) + str(k_roku)
            nr_rekl = entry_01.get()

            nr_szt_w_rekl = entry_szt1.get()

            ean = barcode.get('code128', ('SVC^' + data_biezaca + '^' + nr_rekl + '^' + nr_szt_w_rekl))

            entry_03.insert(0, ean)
            # print(ean)

            ean.get_fullcode()
            filename = ean.save('code12')
            options = dict(compress=True,
                           module_height=6.0,  # 6.3
                           module_width=0.24,  # 0.28
                           text_distance=5.0,
                           font_size=7.0,
                           center_text=True,
                           quiet_zone=1.0)
            filename = ean.save('code12', options)

            """zamiana na pdf"""

            drawing = svg2rlg("code12.svgz")
            renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "file.pdf")  # zamiana na PDF
            # renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="PNG") #zamiana na PNG

            os.startfile("file.pdf", "print")


Generowanie_kodu = Generator()

button_003 = Button(pageq,
                    text="Generuj kod",
                    font="none 20",
                    command=Generowanie_kodu.generator)
button_003.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", Generowanie_kodu.generator)  
button_003.place(x=1112, y=95)

okno.bind("<Control_L><g>", Generowanie_kodu.generator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
class Generator:
    def generator(self, event=None):  # <- give event a default value.
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an `__init__` function in your class:

```
Class Generator:
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event
```

Then you can use self.event for event

Comment: Now I am showing this error: **  TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**

Comment: You need to give a value for event, i'm not sure how it will work otherwise